# PHP stuck on "waiting for localhost"

Tags: php, apache, sockets, irc

Before getting into more detail, I just wanted to clarify that I am a pretty fresh, new PHP programmer. I am not even sure if I set it all up correctly to be honest.
Please bear with me.

I am having troubles with programming a pretty basic IRC Twitch.tv Bot. Whenever I try to open/refresh the page, it gets stuck up on "waiting for localhost", and I've got absolutely no idea why.

I encountered that whenever I remove the loop, it seems to load, and It displays "0 0 resource(2) of type (stream)",
but from what I've gathered online the loop is essential.

I am running Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2.12 (cli). Only testing on localhost for now.

Please help, I'm stumped.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

// info hidden for privacy reasons
$channel = "#channelname";
$server = "irc.chat.twitch.tv";
$port = 6667;
$nick = "botsname";
$pass = "oauth:xxxxxxxxx";

$socket = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 15);
echo $errno." ".$errstr;

fputs($socket,"PASS ".$pass."\r\n");
fputs($socket,"NICK ".$nick."\r\n");

echo var_dump($socket);

fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$channel."\r\n");

while(1) {

    while($data = fgets($socket, 256)) {

        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);
        if($ex[0] == "PING") 
        {
            fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\r\n");
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: There are way easier methods of running a TCP server than using these functions, which basically just hook into the low-level C APIs on your system. I suggest looking at `stream_socket_server()`.

Comment: Have you tried having it echo non-variable data in the loop, just to ensure it's running?

Comment: `while (1)` will create an infinite loop so the server will never finish executing the script.

Comment: `flush()` isn't always able to actually push the content all the way to the browser. Some servers/configs/browsers might still buffer the content. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php): _"flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser"_ and _"Several servers, especially on Win32, will still buffer the output from your script until it terminates before transmitting the results to the browser."_